# Programming Puzzle: How to paint a board?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, puzzle

There is a `N x M` board we should paint. We can paint either an entire row or an entire column at once. Given an `N x M` matrix of colours of all board cells find the minimal number of painting operations to paint the board.

For example: we should paint a 3 x 3 board as follows (R - red, B - blue, G - green):

B, B, B
B, R, R
B, G, G

The minimal number of painting operations is 4:

- Paint row 0 with Blue
- Paint row 1 with Red
- Paint row 2 with Green
- Paint column 0 with Blue

How would you solve it ?

Comment: Can you give more background? especially what is the expected board size? what complexity are you expecting?

Comment: @amit Yes, you are right. The board is at most 50 x 50 and the number of colours is at most 10.

Comment: Something should be said about feasibility. Obviously, boards without a single row or column with the same color everywhere cannot be solved.

Comment: @flodel what should be said about feasibility for instance ?

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a fun problem. Let me take a shot at it with some pseudocode.

```
Function MinPaints(Matrix) Returns Integer
    If the matrix is empty return 0
    Find all rows and columns which have a single color
    If there are none, return infinity, since there is no solution
    Set the current minimum to infinity
    For each row or column with single color:
        Remove the row/column from the matrix
        Call MinPaints with the new matrix
        If the result is less than the current minimum, set the current minimum to the result
    End loop
    Return the current minimum + 1
End Function
```

I think that will solve your problem, but I didn't try any optimization or anything. This may not be fast enough though, I don't know. I doubt this problem is solvable in sub-exponential time.

Here is how this algorithm would solve the example:

```
BBB
BRR
BGG
|
+---BRR
|   BGG
|   |
|   +---RR
|   |   GG
|   |   |
|   |   +---GG
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   +---[]
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   Solvable in 0
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   Solvable in 1
|   |   |
|   |   +---RR
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   +---[]
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   Solvable in 0
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   Solvable in 1
|   |   |
|   |   Solvable in 2
|   |
|   Solvable in 3
|                       BB
+---Another branch with RR ...
|                       GG
Solvable in 4
```

Comment: `If the result is -1, return -1` I am not sure this is correct, it only means this specific branch leads to no solution, but there may be a different branch (which will be discovered later in the for loop) which will lead to a correct solution. [It can be solved by returning INFINITY when there is no solution, and treating it like any other result]

Comment: You may be right, but I can't figure out how that situation would occur. I have a gut feeling it can't.

Comment: Could be, but at the very least - the INFINITY solution is more elegant because it requires less special cases handlings, IMO :)

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this would in fact be solvable quickly by taking the longest solid row/column instead of iterating through them all.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you can try an **informed exhaustive search**.

Let your states graph be: `G=(V,E)` where `V = {all possible boards}` and `E = {(u,v) | you can move from board u to v within a single operation}`.

- Note that you do not need to generate the graph in advance - you can generate it on the fly, using a `successors(board)` function, that return all the successors of the given board.

You will also need `h:V->R` - an [admissible heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) that evaluates the board<sup>1</sup>.

Now, you can run [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm), or [bi-directional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) BFS search [or combination of both], your source will be a white board, and your target is the requested board. Because we use admissible heuristic function - A* is both [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Admissibility_and_optimality) (always finds a solution if one exists) and [optimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Admissibility_and_optimality) (finds the shortest solution), it will find the best solution. [same goes for bi-directional BFS].

**drawbacks:**

- Though the algorithm is informed, it will have exponential behavior.
  But if it is an interview question, I believe a non-efficient
  solution is better then no solution.
- Though complete and optimal - if there is no solution - the algorithm may be stuck in an infinite loop, or a very long loop at the very least until it realizes it has exuahsted all possibilities.

(1) example for admissible heuristic is `h(board) = #(miscolored_squares)/max{m,n}`